# Object_hook not given phpserialize

Tags: php, python, serialization

I'm developing a python app using the library phpserialize. The problem is that now I'm facing an error and I can't find a way to solve it:
I get this serialized data from a php web service:

`a:5:{s:10:"attributes";a:53:{s:9:"entity_id";s:2:"97";s:14:"entity_type_id";s:1:"4";s:16:"attribute_set_id";s:1:"4";s:7:"type_id";s:6:"simple";s:3:"sku";s:5:"16101";s:10:"created_at";s:19:"2013-05-29 14:59:05";s:10:"updated_at";s:19:"2013-08-08 07:38:41";s:11:"has_options";s:1:"1";s:16:"required_options";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:65:"Cuchillo Tactico Combat-Tec negro Aitor dureza de 55/58 HRc 16101";s:10:"meta_title";s:87:"Comprar Cuchillo Tactico Combat-Tec negro Aitor dureza de 55/58 HRc 16101 8435076573875";s:16:"meta_description";s:200:"Comprar Cuchillo Tactico Combat-Tec negro Aitor dureza de 55/58 HRc 16101 8435076573875 hasta un 50% mÃ¡s econÃ³mico que en tiendas. Miles de referencias a tu disposiciÃ³n. EnvÃ­o Urgente. InfÃ³rmate!";s:5:"image";s:17:"/1/6/16101_37.png";s:11:"small_image";s:17:"/1/6/16101_37.png";s:9:"thumbnail";s:17:"/1/6/16101_37.png";s:7:"url_key";s:39:"cuchillo-tactico-combat-tec-negro-aitor";s:8:"url_path";s:44:"cuchillo-tactico-combat-tec-negro-aitor.html";s:13:"custom_design";N;s:17:"options_container";s:10:"container2";s:22:"gift_message_available";N;s:11:"page_layout";N;s:22:"country_of_manufacture";N;s:12:"msrp_enabled";s:1:"2";s:30:"msrp_display_actual_price_type";s:1:"4";s:7:"videoid";N;s:13:"c2c_long_hoja";s:4:"16.5";s:16:"c2c_espesor_hoja";s:3:"4.5";s:12:"manufacturer";N;s:5:"color";s:1:"1";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";s:12:"tax_class_id";s:1:"5";s:10:"visibility";s:1:"4";s:21:"enable_googlecheckout";s:1:"1";s:12:"is_recurring";s:1:"0";s:11:"is_imported";s:1:"0";s:9:"proveedor";s:2:"43";s:5:"price";s:7:"57.8100";s:6:"weight";s:6:"0.0000";s:13:"special_price";N;s:4:"cost";N;s:4:"msrp";N;s:17:"special_from_date";N;s:15:"special_to_date";N;s:14:"news_from_date";N;s:12:"news_to_date";N;s:18:"custom_design_from";N;s:16:"custom_design_to";N;s:11:"description";s:1672:"<p>Cuchillo AITOR modelo Combat-Tec con hoja negra de 16,5 Cm. con sierra superior. Acero Molibdeno Vanadio con prueba de dureza. Mango de micarta negra. Incluye funda de poliamida negra.</p><br /><table id="product-attribute-specs-table" class="data-table"><colgroup><col width="25%" /> <col /> </colgroup><br /><tbody><br /><trclass="first odd"><th class="label">C&oacute;digo</th><br /><td class="data last">16101</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="even"><th class="label">Marcas</th><br /><td class="data last">Aitor</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="odd"><thclass="label">Longitud hoja</th><br /><td class="data last">16.5</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="even"><th class="label">Longitud total</th><br /><td class="data last">28</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="odd"><th class="label">Material hoja</th><br /><td class="data last">Acero Aitor al cromo negro</td><br /></tr><br /><trclass="even"><th class="label">Funda</th><br /><td class="data last">No</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="odd"><th class="label">Espesor hoja</th><br /><td class="data last">4.5</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="even"><th class="label">Material mango</th><br /><td class="data last">Micarta</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="odd"><th class="label">Presentaci&oacute;n</th><br /><td class="data last">Estuche de cart&oacute;n</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="even"><thclass="label">Observaciones</th><br /><td class="data last">No</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="odd"><th class="label">Peso</th><br /><td class="data last">291</td><br /></tr><br /><tr class="last even"><th class="label">C&oacute;digo EAN</th><br /><td class="data last">8435076573875</td><br /></tr><br /></tbody><br /></table>";s:17:"short_description";s:88:"Cuchillo Tactico Combat-Tec negro de la marca Aitor dureza de 55/58 HRc Referencia 16101";s:12:"meta_keyword";s:87:"Comprar Cuchillo Tactico Combat-Tec negro Aitor dureza de 55/58 HRc 16101 8435076573875";s:20:"custom_layout_update";N;s:10:"is_salable";s:1:"1";s:10:"stock_item";O:13:"Varien_Object":7:{s:8:"*_data";a:1:{s:11:"is_in_stock";s:1:"1";}s:18:"*_hasDataChanges";b:0;s:12:"*_origData";N;s:15:"*_idFieldName";N;s:13:"*_isDeleted";b:0;s:16:"*_oldFieldsMap";a:0:{}s:17:"*_syncFieldsMap";a:0:{}}}s:6:"custom";a:2:{s:9:"drop_down";a:1:{s:5:"abcde";a:3:{i:0;s:3:"123";i:1;s:3:"321";i:2;s:3:"231";}}s:5:"radio";a:1:{s:10:"Jajejijoju";a:3:{i:0;s:1:"G";i:1;s:1:"M";i:2;s:1:"P";}}}s:10:"categorias";a:5:{i:0;a:1:{s:16:"Default Category";s:12:"Root Catalog";}i:1;a:1:{s:7:"Default";s:16:"Default Category";}i:2;a:1:{s:12:"CuchillerÃ­a";s:7:"Default";}i:3;a:1:{s:9:"Cuchillos";s:12:"CuchillerÃ­a";}i:4;a:1:{s:31:"Cuchillos Militares y tÃ¡cticos";s:9:"Cuchillos";}}s:10:"inventario";s:8:"999.0000";s:7:"galeria";a:1:{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"url";s:71:"http://foo.es/bar.png";s:5:"label";s:0:"";s:8:"position";s:1:"1";}}}`

And when unserializing it, the following error is displayed:

raise ValueError('object in serialization dump but '
ValueError: object in serialization dump but object_hook not given.

I've googled the error, but I only end up in the source code.
Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "your" library phpserialize? This site isn't affiliated with the makers of phpserialize; StackOverflow isn't the phpserialize support forum or anything like that.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, editted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation on the [PyPI page of phpserialize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/phpserialize) contains some documentation, namely:

> An object hook is a function that takes the name of the class and a
>   dict with the instance data as arguments. The instance data keys are
>   in PHP format which usually is not what you want. To convert it into
>   Python identifiers you can use the convert_member_dict function. For
>   more information about that, have a look at the next section. Here an
>   example for a simple object hook:
>
> ```
> >>> class User(object):
> ...     def __init__(self, username):
> ...         self.username = username
> ...
> >>> def object_hook(name, d):
> ...     cls = {'WP_User': User}[name]
> ...     # The following was added by me -Antti
> ...     d = convert_member_dict(d)
> ...     return cls(**d)
> ...
> >>> user = loads(data, object_hook=object_hook)
> >>> user.username
> 'admin'
> ```

Thus for all classes not supported by phpserialize directly, you need to write a matching class in Python and return instances of them from the `object_hook`.